# C++ null pointer argument as optional argument alternative in C#

Tags: c#, c++, null, optional-parameters

I need to translate/rewrite some C++ code in C#. For quite a few methods, the person who wrote the C++ code had done something like this in the prototype,

```
float method(float a, float b, int *x = NULL);
```

And then in the method something like this,

```
float method(float a, float b, int *x) {

    float somethingElse = 0;
    int y = 0;

    //something happens here
    //then some arithmetic operation happens to y here

    if (x != NULL) *x = y;

    return somethingElse;

}
```

I've confirmed that `x` is an optional parameter for the method, but now I'm having trouble rewriting this in C#. Unless I use pointers and dip unsafe mode I'm not really sure how to do this since `int` cannot be `null`.

I have tried something like this,

```
public class Test
{
    public static int test(ref int? n)
    {
        int x = 10;
        n = 5;
        if (n != null) { 
            Console.WriteLine("not null");
            n = x;
            return 0; 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("is null");
        return 1;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        int? i = null;
        //int j = 100;
        test(ref i);
        //test(ref j);
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

If I uncomment the lines with the variable `j` in the `main()` method, the code does not compile and says that the type `int` does not match the type `int?`. But either way, these methods will be used later and `int` will be passed into them, so I'm not really keen on using the `int?` to maintain compatibility.

I have looked into optional arguments in C#, but that still doesn't mean I can use `null` as a default value for `int`, and I do not know which values this variable won't encounter.

I have also looked into the `??` null-coalescing operator, but this seems to be the reverse of what I'm trying to do.

Could I get some advice on what I should do please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If y is an out variable, maybe use C#'s `out` instead of ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you want an optional `out` parameter.

I would do it with overrides in C#.

```
public static float method(float a, float b, out int x){
    //Implementation
}
public static float method(float a, float b){
    //Helper
    int x;
    return method(a, b, out x);
}
```

Comment: But I think the C++ code did not intend to pass by reference, which what the C# out tends to do. It needed a pointer to an int, and C# can do that with the ref keyword but that cannot be null. Ehm.

Comment: The C++ code is "passing by referece", although in c++ there is a distinction between references or rvalues and pointers. But, the C++ code is doing what C# calls pass by reference. `ref` and `out` both pass by reference, but `out` only passes back, it doesn't marshal the origin object.

Comment: The C++ is passing a pointer with a default value of NULL. In the C++ code where it checks for NULL, now just always assume it is not null and pass back the value, then the helper method will discard it when it cleans up its stack. In your C# code, no longer pass the value x unless you want it back, i.e. simply don't pass `null` or anything when you don't need the x.

Answer (score 0):

`j` should be declared as null-able as well to match the parameter type. Both `i` and `j` then shall be passed, as them, to your function that receives a null-able int parameter.

Also you are assigning a value to `n` inside your function, hence your code will always hit the `not null` case, whatever you try.

This should work:

```
        public static int test(int? n) // without the keyword ref
        {
            int x = 10;
            //n = 5; // Why was that??
            if (n != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not null");
                n = x;
                return 0;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("is null");
            return 1;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int? i = null; // nullable int
            int? j = 100; // nullable to match the parameter type
            test(i);
            test(j);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

Comment: He wants the ref keyword, I think. Looks like the c++ code was trying to use the optional input as an optional return value.